# Change file permission from -rwxrwxr-x to drwxrwxr-x

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

I have a php file which is trying to read and write xml files on my Ubuntu server, however the problem is that it does not have permission to do this (permission denied error).

I have tried the following `chown www-data read_write.php` with no luck

What is the proper way to change permission for this file?

**more info**

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 14092 Sep  6 12:33 read_write.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are a little confused...

The "d" character in front of your string means only that this is a directory, not a file. You should look at your XML's permissions instead!

Comment: xml has the right permission `drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  6 12:38 xml` but I still get a permission denied error.

Comment: @mk_89 A file cannot have permissions `drwxrwxr-x`, since the `d` implies a directory...

Comment: xml is a directory, not a file. You need to look at your XML's files, not directory.

Comment: Ok I see what you guys mean, the actual file has the permission `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: chmod g+wr $your_xml_file - Assuming that it's owner is also www-data:www-data

Comment: It turns out the file was under `root` instead of `www-data,` permision has been changed now

Comment: Now : chmod g+wr $your_xml_file

Answer (score 1):

Just check where is it writing the files, which directory and either do `chmod 777 /path/to/xml/directory` or chown it to the username and group which either apache is running as or in case you're using fcgi or similar(like php-fpm) chown it to the username and group which the php fcgi/php-fpm processes are running as.